# Gracefully Handle Tel URL

Tags: javascript, html, tel

I have a link on my website:

```
<a href="tel:0123456789">call me, maybe</a>
```

That's great for browsers that can initiate calls but it degrades with the elegance of a hippopotamus. Something like:

```
<h1>The address wasn't understood</h1>
```

I thought of attaching on `onclick` listener and showing a popup with the number. However, although the listener runs, the browser still follows the url (and so shows the error) and I don't think there's a reliable way to detect whether there's a `tel:` protocol handler.

Is there a good solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would work where you look to see if the device automatically wraps a telephone number.

```
<div id="testTel" style="display:none">+1 (111) 111-1111</div>
var isTelSupported = (function () {
    var div = document.querySelector("#testTel"),
        hasAnchor = document.getElementsByTagName("a").length > 0;
        div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
    return hasAnchor;
}());
alert(isTelSupported);
```